# Analiytics: Can I set a goal on multiple events?

Tags: google-analytics

We have a popup dialogue that requests users email address or facebook login.

The page behind the popup loads, so a page view is counted.

We want to measure:

- How many users ignored the popup completely
- How many users engaged the popup, but don't complete the process (we trigger an event when the user performs actions defined as "engaging")
- How many users completed the popup

Bounce rates aren't telling because some users won't receive the popup.

We are basically triggering events "PopupDisplayed" "PopupEngaged" and "PopupComplete", with labels to differentiate between email and  facebook.

But I don't think I can set goals to count "Users who received 'PopupDisplayed' AND 'PopupComplete'" events, so I can count how many users both saw the popup and completed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally you'd want to use a funnel to visualise where people are dropping out of your process before completion; however, the current GA goal tracking for events doesn't allow you to set up a funnel.

You could try changing from sending events at each stage of the process to sending virtual page views; this would enable you to use a funnel, but you might not want to mix page views and events together.