# Grouping multiple goals in goal flow report

Tags: google-analytics, conversions, goal-tracking, event-tracking, goals

I've set up events and goals, and am able to see conversions in all my reports. However, one problem I'm having is that I can't seem to bundle multiple goals together in the Goal Flow report. I have a website for an app with events - and corresponding goals - that trigger when a user forwards to each app store, but I would like to get a goal flow report that shows the flow to a total of both those events/goals. Is this an option?

I've been trying to find more information on "Goal Sets", but seems like the feature is [set to be retired](http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2013/06/10/google-analytics-goals-ui-shakeup/#sr=g&m=o&cp=or&ct=-tmc&st=(opu%20qspwjefe)&ts=1422053660), and the pages I've found on it have [very little info](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3046783?hl=en&ref_topic=1007030). I also don't want to set up a goal that is [triggered by multiple events](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/28278/analiytics-can-i-set-a-goal-on-multiple-events), since that usually ends up in double counting of conversions.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is, can I group multiple goals together to make a goal flow the answer is that you wouldn't use multiple goals to create a goal flow but funnels from goals. Also know that you can only create funnels on URI based goals. Here's a [link](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/google-analytics-goals-funnels-tips/)